# ignoring frontpage.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on an existing website created in codeigniter.
Whenever a user enters a page, he gets redirected to frontpage.php, that checks if the user is logged in, if not he gets redirected to the login page.
Now, I have one page where this frontpage.php shouldnt be executed, and any user can enter it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the exact question? Be more clear and have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried to modify the new page that shud be loaded without checking frontpage.php, but any code is only executed after going to frontpage.php... is there any way to check in the frontpage where the user was trying to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-route everything to your pages controller and use this as your default

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';

$route['(.*)'] = 'pages/index/$1';
```

-

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $currentUser = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->currentUser = Auth::getCurrentUserObject(); //check user is logged in
    }

    public function index($uri='home')
    {

        $sizeOfSegments = sizeof($this->uri->rsegments);

        if ($sizeOfSegments >= 3)
        {       
            $uri = $this->uri->rsegments[3];
        } 
        else
        {
            $uri = 'home';
        }

        $pageFound = Page::find($uri); //query the database

        if (!$pageFound)
        {
            return show_404($uri); // find out where there were headed 
        }

        unset($sizeOfSegments, $uri);

        if(is_null($this->currentUser) OR !$this->currentUserHasPermissionToViewThisPage OR !$pageIsNotPublic)
        {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        $this->load->view();

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont really understand what's happening, what does Page::find($uri) do?

Comment: Page::find in your case doesn't do anything, unless you are using an ORM such as php-activerecord or Doctrine etc. I was just stating Page::find would be your DB query

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and solved it this way by using some online tutorials

1: Make a seperate loginpage (ex login.php) prior to the 'frontpage.php'.

2: Pass the login, password and a session variable to the frontpage.

3: Recode you 'frontpage.php' to check for the session variable passed by 'login.php'.

If u entered the page trough the normal way it will use the normal login.
if u entered the page trough the new 'login.php' page it will be picked up by the recoded 'frontpage.php' and bypass the normal way.

Hope this helps

Grtz

Answer (score 0):

make new controller

```
class Newpage extends CI_Controller {

  public function index(){
    $this->load->view('newpage');
  }
}
```

now goto

**yourhost.com/index.php/newpage**

Answer (score 0):

May be your default Controller have a coding of checking whether user is logged or not. Please remove or change the code in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to delete the controller, it works like that!

Comment: Yes i are very serious, on my school they teach me how code igniter works! I has good points